# Firefox addon undefined var from frame

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon

So basicly I'm injecting a script into a frame to get a specific variable but I get the following error: *content.exenv2.exerciseframe.singletons is undefined*

But when I access this variable thru to firebug console it works. Also I can access other variable from the frame just not the one I need

**Full Error**

```
error: dwh: An exception occurred.
TypeError: content.exenv2.exerciseframe.singletons is undefined
resource://jid1-os5kkx1kvkogmq-at-jetpack/dwh/data/inject.js 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resource://jid1-os5kkx1kvkogmq-at-jetpack/dwh/data/inject.js", line 2, i
n
    var length = content.exenv2.exerciseframe.singletons.entries["TkExerciseItem
s_()"].length;
```

**First 2 lines of code**

```
var test = content.exenv2.exerciseframe.loadingTimer; //This works
var length = content.exenv2.exerciseframe.singletons.entries["TkExerciseItems_()"].length; //Error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently a Firefox addon can't access prototype variables which was the case for *singletons*.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/accessing-the-dom.html

As the link above states, such variables should be accessed using the unsafeWindow.

So the working code would be:

```
var length = unsafeWindow.content.exenv2.exerciseframe.singletons.entries["TkExerciseItems_()"].length;
```